# Как перенести данные из одной таблицы в другую максимально быстро?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем доброго времечка!

Господа, нужна ваша помощь

В базе есть таблица с неотформатированными данными (чуть больше 2 500 000 строк), нужно перенсти их в другую таблицу, предварительно отформатировав (форматирование и добавление происходит в хранимке). Теперь вопрос, как это сделать максимально быстро? Пробовал и через WHILE и через курсор, работает очень медленно... Может бысть вы знаете какие-нибудь хаки?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_Insert_Point 
    @CodeId int = 0,
    @Code nvarchar(200) = NULL,
    @Latitude nvarchar(70) = NULL,
    @Longitude nvarchar(70) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Point geography;
    SET @Point = geography::Point(TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, @Longitude), TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, @Latitude), 4326); 

    DECLARE @PointString nvarchar(100);
    SET @PointString = CONCAT('POINT(', @Longitude, ', ', @Latitude, ')');

    DECLARE @PointCenter geography;
    SET @PointCenter = @Point.EnvelopeCenter(); 

    DECLARE @PointCenterString nvarchar(100);
    SET @PointCenterString = CONCAT('POINT(', @PointCenter.Lat, ', ', @PointCenter.Long, ')');

    DECLARE @IdentityOutpurFpc table (ID int);

    INSERT INTO dbo.Winkworth_Location (Code, Source, Type, Name, County, Enabled, LocationString, LocationCenterString, IsPoint)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.LocationID INTO @IdentityOutpurFpc
    VALUES(@Code, 'UkFullPostCode', 'UkFullPostCode', @Code, '', 1, @PointString, @PointCenterString, 1);

    DECLARE @RowIdFPC integer = 0;
    SET @RowIdFPC = (SELECT ID FROM @IdentityOutpurFpc);

    INSERT INTO dbo.Winkworth_LocationSpacial (LocationID, LocationGeography, LocationCenterGeography)
    VALUES(@RowIdFPC, @Point, @PointCenter);

    UPDATE dbo.Winkworth_FullPostCodes SET IsDone = 1 WHERE CodeId = @CodeId;
END
GO
```

Comment: Что подразумевается под "форматированием"? Запуск процедуры для каждой записи таблицы не будет работать быстро.

Comment: Форматирование представляет собой обработку строковых значений (координат Latitude и Longitude) в формат geography и добавление некоторых статических данных. И все это хранимка добавляет сразу в две таблицы. Нужны хоть какие-то варианты, потому-что я уже хз как быть)

Comment: Да никак, набраться терпения и ждать. Или заниматься оптимизацией процедуры - кстати, без надежды на успех... а из хаков - разве что "быстро уволиться, пусть другие с этим трахаются".

Comment: Добавьте побольше информации о прецессе, есть трейсфлаг 610, который включает режим неполного протоколирования, можно вместе с лочить таблицу TABLOCK(X), можно балком вставлять, но мне кажется ваша проблема в самой ХП.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov добавить код хранимки

Comment: А медленно это сколько записей в секунду?

Comment: я пробовал просто пройтись в цикле While по данным, и получить текущую запись на каждом шаге, и это было не быстро в минуту может штук 200 (примерно), с хранимкой, кмк все еще сложнее

Comment: С виду вроде-бы ничего такого в процедуре нет, чтобы нельзя было RBAR-код переписать в set-based.